# Jquery - keyup event checking input value in three fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keyup

I'm looking for a form validation solution. I have three number fields. 1st of them have values: min=50, max=100. 2nd and 3rd TOGETHER will have max=50 but it cant be split in same way, so max=25. I thought of using IF statements, but that solution will be too complicated. How it should work:

- 1st input value=50, 2nd value=25, 3rd value=25,
- 1st input value=60, 2nd value=0, 3rd value=50,
- 1st input value=75, 2nd value=20, 3rd value=5,
- etc

I have some code to validate proper data input:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

    $('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th1 = $('input[name="value_1"]');
        var $th2 = $('input[name="value_2"]');
        var $th3 = $('input[name="value_3"]');

        $th1.val( $th1.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function(){ return ''; }) );
        $th2.val( $th2.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function(){ return ''; }) );
        $th3.val( $th3.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function(){ return ''; }) );
    });
});
```

and working fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/04d5gkxd/2/

So in other words, group of fields: 2nd and 3rd must check the current value of 1st input, and base on that give the user possibility of picking proper value from 2nd and 3rd. Any ideas?

Comment: have you considered using jQuery UI "sliders" instead?

Comment: p.s. it's *really* not a good idea to make every input change alter the content of all three inputs.

Comment: p.p.s. and also consider using `$el.val(function(...))` to perform read-modify-write, not `$el.val($el.val()...)

Comment: There is an edit functionality for comments you know. @Alnitak

Comment: @Glubus If I wanted to make one really big comment, I would have - in my view the points were better made separately.

Comment: @Alnitak gosh no need to get all mad about it, it's just that 3 comments in a row like that might discourage other users to read the rest. No offense was meant.

Comment: @Alnitak - dummy question yet i will ask - what is the difference between range and jQueryUI sliders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alnitak suggested in the comments, you would be better suited to make the values set by some slider controls. You could have one which is a range of `50 - 100`, and a second which is `0 - 50` that governs both the final values. Something like this:

```
<div id="sliderA" class="slider"></div>
<div id="sliderB" class="slider"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="value_1" id="value_1" value="50" />
<input type="hidden" name="value_2" id="value_2" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="value_3" id="value_3" value="0" />
```

```js
$('#sliderA').slider({
    min: 50,
    max: 100,
    change: function(e, ui) {
        $('#value_1').val(ui.value);
    }
});
$('#sliderB').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    change: function(e, ui) {
        $('#value_2').val(ui.value);
        $('#value_3').val(50 - ui.value);
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/04d5gkxd/3/)

Comment: thanks. I will take a look on it and will redefine what I have currently. Your solution indeed works (& looks!) better than mine..

Comment: one more thing. when it comes to sliderB, why i cant change max into variable? you know, when for example in sliderA value will be 70, in sliderB max should be 30 (as i mentioned, in total we should always have 100). I even tried to make it but something is wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/04d5gkxd/4/

Comment: I've managed to create something which is closer to the final, yet current problem is that splited data into two fields is equal: https://jsfiddle.net/ptkxqakd/8/